# SQL Server : Select value from record that has max column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I has some table with 3 columns: `ObjectID,  ChangedOn, NewValue`.

Sample data:

```
ObjectId                                NewValue            ChangedOn
50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2    Closed              2012-07-13 15:14:35.000
50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2    ActiveForSupport    2012-07-13 15:13:33.930
50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2    Closed              2012-07-13 15:12:47.787
50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2    ActiveForSupport    2012-07-13 15:11:28.540
50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2    Closed              2012-07-13 14:52:10.797
D9001738-E089-43B3-8E80-6993601C4E70    Closed              2012-06-27 08:03:27.550
```

Need group data by `ObjectId` and show 3 columns: `ObjectId, NewValue` for row that contains max value for `ChangedOn` into group and max value for `ChangedOn` into current group
For test data I must get following result:

```
 ObjectId                              NewValue            ChangedOn
     50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2      Closed           2012-07-13 15:14:35.000
     D9001738-E089-43B3-8E80-6993601C4E70      Closed           2012-06-27 08:03:27.550
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need the ugly `<br/>` and `<pre>` tags, either!

Comment: For test data i can get following result:

Comment: 50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2    Closed              2012-07-13 15:14:35.000

Comment: D9001738-E089-43B3-8E80-6993601C4E70    Closed              2012-06-27 08:03:27.550

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE test3(ObjectId uniqueidentifier,NewValue varchar(100),ChangedOn datetime)
INSERT INTO test3
VALUES('50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2','Closed','2012-07-13 15:14:35.000'),
('50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2','ActiveForSupport','2012-07-13 15:13:33.930'),
('50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2','Closed','2012-07-13 15:12:47.787'),
('50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2','ActiveForSupport','2012-07-13 15:11:28.540'),
('50E37991-777C-4813-B436-C6082CCA6BE2','Closed','2012-07-13 14:52:10.797'),
('D9001738-E089-43B3-8E80-6993601C4E70','Closed','2012-06-27 08:03:27.550')

select t1.ObjectId,t1.NewValue,t2.maxChangedOn  from test3 t1 inner join 
(select ObjectId,MAX(ChangedOn) maxChangedOn from test3
group by ObjectId) t2
on t1.ObjectId =t2.ObjectId and t1.ChangedOn =t2.maxChangedOn
```